# How to explicitly cast an object using the user-defined operator in the derived class

Tags: c#, casting

Consider the following code:

```
  class A {
    public static explicit operator int(A a) {
      Console.WriteLine("User-defined explicit cast A");
      return 42;
    }
  }
  
  class B : A {
    public static explicit operator int(B a) {
      Console.WriteLine("User-defined explicit cast B");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  public void TestCast() {
    A b = new B();
    Console.WriteLine($"The result is: {(int) b)}");
  }
```

This prints:

```
User-defined explicit cast A
The result is: 42
```

Is there a way for me to cast using the instance's type's user-defined cast operator at runtime, without knowing what the instance type actually is at compile time?

Comment: if you want the method to be virtually dispatched, use a virtual method, rather than a static method.  You can have the static method call the virtual method if you want to maintain the syntax.

Comment: The extended problem is this, I want to call this on an object of generic type, and I do not want to restrict the generic type to a base class. I found a way around this, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While overload resolution usually happens at compile time, casting the object to `dynamic` forces it to be resolved at runtime.

```
class A {
    public static explicit operator int(A a) {
      Console.WriteLine("User-defined explicit cast A");
      return 42;
    }
  }
  
  class B : A {
    public static explicit operator int(B a) {
      Console.WriteLine("User-defined explicit cast B");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  public void TestCast() {
    A b = new B();
    Console.WriteLine($"The result is: {(int) (dynamic) b)}");
  }
```

This now prints:

```
User-defined explicit cast B
The result is: 1
```